# Ajax success function not working in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am trying to validate a basic login form with username and password fields. I need to validate username and password from `check.php` ajax page. There is no problem in ajax request and response. I am getting proper response from ajax page. But Ajax success function is not working properly.

**ajaxrequest.html**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#login', function(){
        $(document).on('click', '#submit', function() {
        if($('#username').val().length > 0 && $('#password').val().length > 0){
                $.ajax({
                    url : 'serverurl/check.php',
                    data: {action : 'login', formData : $('#check-user').serialize()},
                    type: 'post',                   
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $.mobile.loading(true);
                        alert("beforesend");
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        $.mobile.loading(false);
                        alert("complete");
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log("Ajax response");   
                        res = JSON.stringify(result);
                        if(res.status == "success"){    
                        resultObject.formSubmitionResult = res.uname;
                        localStorage["login_details"] = window.JSON.stringify(result);
                        $.mobile.changePage("#second");
                }else{
                        $.mobile.changePage("#login");
                        alert("incorrect login");           
                }
                    },
                    error: function (request,error) {
                        alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
                    }
                });                   
        } else {
            alert('Fill all fields');
        }           
            return false;
        });    
});
```

Here i have added my ajax page. This page only validates posted username and password. Finally it returns `json` object. What am i doing wrong?

**serverurl/check.php**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if(isset($_POST['formData']) && isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'login'){
    parse_str($_POST['formData'],$searchArray);
    $uname = "arun";
    $pwd = "welcome";
    $resultArray = array();
    if($uname == $searchArray['username'] && $pwd == $searchArray['password'])      
    {
        $resultArray['uname'] = $searchArray['username'];
        $resultArray['pwd'] = $searchArray['password'];
        $resultArray['status'] = 'success';
    }else{
        $resultArray['status'] = 'failed';
    }
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}
```

Comment: Post the response json, any errors, or exceptions.

Comment: Am not getting any errors. Instead, i am not getting response in success function. Directly it goes to error function.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be

```
success: function (result) {
                        console.log("Ajax response");   
                        //don't do this
                        //res = JSON.stringify(result);
                        if(result.status == "success"){    
                        resultObject.formSubmitionResult = result.uname;
                        localStorage["login_details"] = window.JSON.stringify(result);
                        $.mobile.changePage("#second");
                }else{
                        $.mobile.changePage("#login");
                        alert("incorrect login");           
                }
```

After `JSON.stringify` you are accessing like `stringJson.status` this will not work. it mast have "parsed" "**json object**" not stringify.

Comment: Thank u for your reply. Am i want to do, jQuery.parseJSON(result) or just remove that stringify?

Comment: just remove stringify .

Comment: I have done as u said. After converted to apk, i installed my apk to my mobile. same problem is there.  when i enters wrong username and password it goes to error function and throwing  error message (Network error has occurred please try again!). Response not getting inside success function

Comment: In browser am getting proper result. When i convert my code to apk, and install into mobile device. it is not working.

Comment: is it goes inside `success`? Can you trace in mobile?

Comment: No it doesnt goes inside success. Directly goes to error function. Thats the problem.

Comment: can you console the error? what error are you getting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98306/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-arun).

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to convert your JSON to String.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#login', function(){
        $(document).on('click', '#submit', function() {
        if($('#username').val().length > 0 && $('#password').val().length > 0){
                $.ajax({
                    url : 'serverurl/check.php',
                    data: {action : 'login', formData : $('#check-user').serialize()},
                    type: 'post',                   
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $.mobile.loading(true);
                        alert("beforesend");
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        $.mobile.loading(false);
                        alert("complete");
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log("Ajax response");   
                        //Don't need to converting JSON to String
                        //res = JSON.stringify(result);
                        //directly use result 
                        if(result.status == "success"){    
                        resultObject.formSubmitionResult = result.uname;
                        localStorage["login_details"] = window.JSON.stringify(result);
                        $.mobile.changePage("#second");
                }else{
                        $.mobile.changePage("#login");
                        alert("incorrect login");           
                }
                    },
                    error: function (request,error) {
                        alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
                    }
                });                   
        } else {
            alert('Fill all fields');
        }           
            return false;
        });    
});
```

Comment: In browser am getting proper result. When i convert my code to apk, and install into mobile device. it is not working.

Comment: this result is not working in andriod if you have to use both then you need to use API this provide result for both.

Comment: I need to clarify one thing clearly. You need to use API. What it means. can u tell me some more detailed?

Comment: No. Now you are talking inside success function. My problem is code doesn't goes inside to success function itself. Directly it goes to error function.

Answer (score 1):

Your AJAX call is perfect but datatype is not declared in ajax

Try with jSON OR JSONP. You will get success.

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'serverurl/check.php',                    
    type: 'post',
    dataType: "json", OR "jsonp",
    async: false,
    data: {action : 'login', formData : $('#check-user').serialize()},
        beforeSend: function() {
        $.mobile.loading(true);
        alert("beforesend");
    },
    complete: function() {
        $.mobile.loading(false);
        alert("complete");
    },
    success: function (result) {
        console.log("Ajax response");   
        alert(JSON.stringify(result)); // Check response in alert then parse according to that
        res = JSON.stringify(result);
        if(res.status == "success"){    
        resultObject.formSubmitionResult = res.uname;
        localStorage["login_details"] = window.JSON.stringify(result);
        $.mobile.changePage("#second");
}else{
        $.mobile.changePage("#login");
        alert("incorrect login");           
}
    },
    error: function (request,error) {
        alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
    }
});
```

Comment: In browser am getting proper result. When i convert my code to apk, and install into mobile device. it is not working.

Comment: Use async: false & jsonp for mobile purpose

Comment: I have tried async & jsonp too. Same problem is there. success function not working

Comment: Alert box not work in apk/mobile better way bind your success result to any <div id="sample"></div>

Comment: To bind a result, My response should go into success function right. My problem is success function is not working. Directly it goes to error function.

Answer (score 1):

Under some circumstances your server might not return the response correctly. Have you tried to handle the actual response code (e.g. if your server returns 200) like this:

```
 $.ajax({
         url : 'serverurl/check.php',
         data: {action : 'login', formData : $('#check-user').serialize()},
         type: 'post', 
         .... 
         statusCode: {
               200: function (response) {
                      // do your stuff here
                    }
         }
 });
```

Comment: I have tried statusCode, inside statusCode i used alert(statusCode), it returns empty [object Object]. I guess we are nearby. What is that?

Comment: try: `alert(response);` or `alert(response.responseText);` depending on what your response looks like...

Comment: alert(response) gives [object Object], alert(response.responseText) gives undefined.

Comment: if i were you, I would debug into the function to see what your response object is. You can do it like this:
`... 200: function(response){debugger;}`
Open your page in your browser with the inspector open and your code should break here. If it does (which it should) just type `response` in the console. This way you can examine what attributes your response object offers you...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am getting success response --- response = Object {uname: "arun", pwd: "welcome", status: "success"}, failure response --- response = Object {status: "failed"}. So i am getting proper response from server. But in mobile apk, inside the success function nothing happens

Comment: then in your statusCode-200 and in your statusCode-403 or 500 (whatever the error is), e.g.: `alert(response.status )`

Comment: Everything works for me in desktop only. In mobile Nothing works for me. Can u come to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98325/discussion-between-remi-and-arun).